# Can all points in the plane be represented like this?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

Solving a task regaring affine geometry, I've come across a problem:

Is it  true that, for every point $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, there  exist $t\in \mathbb{R}, \alpha\in[0,2\pi]$, such that

$$x = t\cos\alpha + \sin \alpha \\ y = t\sin\alpha + \cos \alpha?$$

I don't have any idea how to prove this or find a counterexample. All hints appreciated!

Comment: what about just solving for $\alpha$ and $t$?

Comment: @Ilya It's a 2-nd degree equation with 2 variables, I don't know how to start it, I've tried to use $\sin \alpha = z - t\cos\alpha$ in second equation, but still I can't get equation for $\alpha$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be written as
\begin{align}
&\left(\begin{array}{cr}
\tilde{x} \\ \tilde{y}
\end{array}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cr}
1 &-1 \\ 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cr}
x \\ y
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{cr}
t-1 & 0 \\ 0 & t+1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
\cos\left(\alpha+{\pi}/{4}\right) \\ \sin\left(\alpha+{\pi}/{4}\right)
\end{array}\right).\tag{1}
\end{align}
Since $(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})$ are obtained by rotation of $(x,y)$ by $\pi/4$, it suffices to show that any point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be represented by the right side of (1). This is equivalent to showing that for any point $P=(x,y)$ with $x,y\neq 0$ one can always find $t\neq \pm1$ such that the ellipse
$$\left(\frac{x}{t-1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{t+1}\right)^2=1 \tag{2}$$
passes through $P$ (which is true - think on what happens to this ellipse when $t$ continuously decreases from $\infty$ to $1$, and then from $1$ to $-1$).

Comment: +1. You beat me. I took too long TeX-ing up my arrays for the same argument. :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's play around and see what happens.

I write $a$ for $\alpha$,
$c$ for $\cos \alpha$,
and $s$ for $\sin \alpha$
cause I'm lazy.

We have
$x = t c + s$
and 
$y = t s + c$.

$x^2+y^2 = t^2 c^2+2tcs + s^2 + t^2 s^2 + 2tcs + c^2
= t^2+1+4tsc$.

$xy = t^2 cs + tc^2+t s^2 + sc
= cs(t^2+1)+t$.

We can solve for $cs$ in each of these.

$cs = (x^2+y^2-t^2-1)/(4t)$
and
$cs = (xy-t)/(t^2+1)$
so
$(x^2+y^2-t^2-1)/(4t) = (xy-t)/(t^2+1)$.

Now we can solve for $t$.

$4t(xy-t) = (t^2+1)(x^2+y^2-t^2-1)$
or
$4txy-4t^2 = (t^2+1)(x^2+y^2) - (t^2+1)^2
= t^2(x^2+y^2)+(x^2+y^2)-t^4-2t^2-1
$
so
$t^4-t^2(x^2+y^2+2)+4txy+1=0$.

This is a quartic, unfortunately,
and I don't see an obvious root.

We can also do this:

$xs-yc = (tcs + s^2)-(tsc+c^2)
= s^2-c^2
= 2s^2 - 1
$,
so
$yc = xs-2s^2+1$.

Squaring this,
and using $c^2 = 1-s^2$,
we get another quartic for $s$.

In other words,
we can get equations for
$t$
and $\sin \alpha$,
but they are quartics.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt at a visual interpretation.

The equation is equivalent to

$$ \frac{ x - \sin \alpha} { \cos \alpha} = t = \frac{ y - \cos \alpha} { \sin \alpha},$$

$$ \frac{ y - \cos \alpha } { x - \sin \alpha} = \frac{ \sin \alpha} { \cos \alpha}$$

What this means, is that the slope of the point $(x,y)$ to the point $A=(\sin \alpha, \cos \alpha)$ on the unit circle, is $\tan \alpha$.

Comment: Set $\alpha = \pi/4$ and $t=-1$ to get $(0,0)$

Comment: @MarkBennet that is true. I forgot the -1, which is needed to make it the tangent.

Comment: I did the same and was going to post the same answer!